# GTAG User ID tracking not working

Tags: google-analytics

I've turned on User ID tracking, and am using the following code:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', '<UA-ID>');

//gtag('config', '<UA-ID>', {'user_id': '{% user_display request.user %}'});

// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/setting-values
gtag('set', {'user_id': '{% user_display request.user %}'}); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
```

I've confirmed that the user_id value is being properly set by the JS. Also, I am able to see tracking info, except that it is NOT attached to a user.

Wondering if anyone has set this up before and could help debug. Also, note that I am using GTAG not the older Analytics (which I believe is called UA - Universal Analytics).

Answer (score 10):

I figured this out, User ID has to be set before the pageview event is sent. Maybe just after the function gtag() declaration would help.

I switched over to the older analytics.js since it is much better supported. The same applies there as well.

Comment: Exactly, GA's User-ID documentation is bad when saying "add" but not "insert" this line before gtag('config'...);